# Swift 4: How to initialise a class with values in one line?

Tags: swift, class, initialization, swift4, swift-class

I have a simple class in Swift 4 like this:

```
class Message {

    var messageBody : String = ""
    var sender : String = ""

}
```

And I want to (in one line) populate a variable with an instance of this object.

I tried to do it like this:

```
func retrieveMessages() {
    let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("Messages")
    messageDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
        let text = snapshotValue["MessageBody"]!
        let sender = snapshotValue["Sender"]!
        let message = Message(messageBody: text, sender: sender) // relevant one liner
    }
}
```

But this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Also note, that this:

```
let message = Message()
message.messageBody = text
message.sender = sender
```

works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a **struct** which provides a free *memberwise* initializer

```
struct Message {   

    var messageBody : String 
    var sender : String
}
```

Or in case of a **class** write one

```
class Message {

    var messageBody : String 
    var sender : String

    init(messageBody : String, sender : String) {
       self.messageBody = messageBody
       self.sender = sender
    }
}
```

In both cases there is no need to assign default values.

For further information please read [Swift Language Guide : Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)

Comment: I would also declare the properties as constants. If OP needs to change it just create a new object.

Comment: import Foundation

class Message {
    
    var messageBody : String = ""
    var sender : String = ""
    init(msgBody : String = "MessageBody" , senderText : String = "sender text" ) {
        messageBody = msgBody
        sender = senderText
    }
}
let msg = Message(msgBody: "Hello", senderText: "Mike")
let messge = Message() // default parameters gets printed.
//Are you looking for default parameter ?

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what was missing :)